# How to use "content disposition attachment" in OpenXml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, openxml-sdk, content-disposition

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 site that creates an Excel file using OPEN XML SDK. My controller method generates the OPEN XML Excel document and is downloading it.

But the user should see the Excel file in the browser.

I know

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName + "");
```

is responsible for it. But I don't know how to implement this in openXnl method. I am not using http response here. Or how can I use it? Please help me on this

This is my Excel generating method, and I tried to implement `AddHeader "content-disposition"` but nothing works:

```
public static void GenerateExcelOpenXML(string FolderPath, DataSet tableSet)
{
    WorkbookPart wBookPart = null;
    var datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_");
    string FilePath = FolderPath + "Report_" + datetime + ".xlsx";

    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(FilePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        wBookPart = spreadsheetDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
        wBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        uint sheetId = 1;
        spreadsheetDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

        WorkbookStylesPart wbsp = wBookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();

        wbsp.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet();
        wbsp.Stylesheet.Save();

        foreach (DataTable table in tableSet.Tables)
        {
            WorksheetPart wSheetPart = wBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wSheetPart), 
            SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
            wSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

            Row headerRow = new Row();

            Columns columns = new Columns();
            int ColumnNumber = 1;

            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                cell.StyleIndex = 2;
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);

                Column column1 = new Column();
                column1.Width = 30;
                column1.Min = Convert.ToUInt32(ColumnNumber);
                column1.Max = Convert.ToUInt32(ColumnNumber);
                column1.CustomWidth = true;

                columns.AppendChild(column1);
                ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1;
            }

            wSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(columns);

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                Row row = new Row();

                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dr[column].ToString());
                    cell.StyleIndex = 1;
                    row.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(row);
            }

            sheetId++;

            wSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(sheetData);

            // sheetData.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName + "");       
            // how can I implement here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot set the HTTP headers inside this method - you need to do this in the **controller action** that calls this method to create the Excel file. This method needs to return the generated Excel as a byte array, and then the controller action method needs to return this byte array to the HTTP response stream.

Comment: how i can  convert this methode in to  Excel as a byte array,? I have tried something but none of the methods are working.I used  MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(); but dontknow how to implimnet here